# Thinking of fiance permissible in islam with out talking to each other

Tags: nikah, islamic-basis

Parents of both the parties have agreed to make nikah after few months. And 
girl and boy doesn't talk to each other.Alhamdulillah!
The question her eis..
 can a girl/boy herself/himself imagine a future with him/her or think about that person? (With out talking to each other ) just in their own heart n mind. 
Is this permissible in Islam?

Comment: Why should thinking about somebody one wants to marry be haram? If you have any reasons to think so you should add them to your post else you may follow the ruling that anything is per se halal unless there's a clear text saying otherwise.